# Clamp camera within bounds of a Polygon Collider?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I am making a 2d platformer game and right now I am working on the camera. while I succeeded in clamping the camera inside a rectangular shape, my game involves slopes, so I want my camera to be able to clamp inside a curved shaped too. Can anyone help me find an idea for the code?

Comment: Have you considered using splines to make your camera move along a certain path?

Answer (score 1):

[Cinemachine](https://unity.com/unity/features/editor/art-and-design/cinemachine#cinemachine-2d) gives you a flexible 2D camera controller, with the option to confine it inside a PolygonCollider2D. [This section](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/07/17/cinemachine-for-2d-tips-and-tricks/?_ga=2.86585553.855031758.1616874998-38206564.1566327548) contains explanation for that and other cool things.